# Error : "Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state " when history table is enabled

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables, history-tables

We enabled temporal data (system-versioning history for table) on SQL Server 2017 but when we execute a delete command like below get an error message

> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state

```
delete kelakets where id=5
```

but when we disable the history table for main table and related tables, then execute the delete command it works perfect and nicely.

Disable history command:

```
ALTER TABLE Kelakets SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
ALTER TABLE tableRelated1 SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
ALTER TABLE tableRelated2 SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
```

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for related messages.

Comment: @DanGuzman sql log :
Exception Code    = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION                                                      
Access Violation occurred reading address 000000000000000C                                                   
Input Buffer 86 bytes -

Comment: This could be corruption or a SQL Server bug. Run DBCC to rule out the former, and if clean, create a simplified script that recreates the problem and report on the [feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server).

Comment: @DanGuzman CHECKDB report :  CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database